# One to many relationship without reference in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a one to many relationship as you see here. What I want to do is I want to save school object with student objects without setting schools of student objects. Below code works but hibernate inserts null values to school_id_fk column.

```
public class Student {
....
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "school_id_fk")
private School school;

}

public class School{
....
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "school")
private Set<Student> studentSet = new HashSet<Student>(0);


}
```

and main method;

```
    School school = new School();
    school.setSchoolName("school name");


    Student student = new Student();
    student.setStudentName("studentname1");
    student.setStudentSurname("studentsurname1");
    //student.setSchool(school); I don't want to set this line

    Student student2 = new Student();
    student2.setStudentName("studentname2");
    student2.setStudentSurname("studentsurname2");
    //student2.setSchool(school); I don't want to set this line


    SessionFactory sessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();

    school.getStudentSet().add(student);
    school.getStudentSet().add(student2);

    session.save(school);

    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();
    sessionFactory.close();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Funtik method is correct, however it needs third table.

But your approach is also correct. You can have this relation bidirectional.
If you want to have your `school_id_fk` column *not null* you can use
a common pattern in hibernate with (so called) convenience method:

```
public class Student {
  ....
  @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinColumn(name = "school_id_fk")
  private School school;

}

public class School{
  ....
  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "school")
  private Set<Student> studentSet;

  // this is private setter (used by hibernate internally)
  private void setStudentSet(Set<Student> studentSet) {
    this.studentSet = studentSet;
  }

  // this is public method (exposed API)
  public void addStudent(Student) {
    if (studentSet == null) {
      studentSet = new HashSet<>();
    }

    student.setSchool(this);
    studentSet.add(student);
  }

}
```

As you can see (according to this pattern) you should hide `studentSet` as only hibernate should use `setStudentSet()` setter.
Private setter will do that. But you can expose public API to operate on this set - `addStudent()` in this case.
In `addStudent(student)` method `student` object is added to set and assigned with parent school in **encapsulated way**.

**Summary:** this is common pattern when using hibernate, hide collection setter, expose convenience methods like `addStudent()`.
In this approach you have your FK column always filled, and you can fetch `School` object from `Student` object without HQL query. There is no need for third table in this case.

This is just alternative to @Funtik solution.

Answer (score 1):

MappedBy is not needed in school entity

```
public class School{
....
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "school_id")
private Set<Student> studentSet = new HashSet<Student>(0);
```

and don't use school in the Student entity

```
public class Student {
....

}
```

Comment: When I remove mappedBy property hibernate creates a third table. Is there a way to do this without creating a third table?